# How to compile/update parts of my document only, while still producing a complete document?

Tags: compiling, include

**Context:** When I write a large document, I write each chapter in a different file. All these subfiles are then included (using `\include{<subfile name>}`) in a main file to constitute my document.

When I work on a specific chapter, I use the `\includeonly` command to only compile this specific chapter (and thus speed-up the compilation).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \includeonly{%here, chap2 only will be compiled
%       chap1,
        chap2,
%       chap3
    }
\begin{document}
    \include{chap1}
    \include{chap2}
    \include{chap3}
\end{document}
```

**Problem:** As made obvious by its name, the `\includeonly` command only includes listed subfiles in the compiled document. This makes that in my case, the document produced contains only one chapter.

However, I'd like to have all chapters included in the document produced.

**Question:** How to make `LaTeX` update only one chapter (shorter compiling time) while still producing a `.pdf` that contains every chapter (full document)?

---

Note: I want the "`\updateonly`" command to be versatile, i.e. to easily change the chapter(s) to be updated (or even recompile everything). I would also like to keep auxiliary data untouched (macro definition, cited references, hyperlinks [those from not updated chapters pointing on elements of the updated chapter might obviously be broken, though], acronyms, etc.)

Comment: there is no standard way to do this.

Comment: You can have a separate document for each chapter and combine them into one document using `pdfpages`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Thank you. I imagined this solution - however, I don't find it "versatile" enough as is. I'm also not quite sure how I could generate one ToC and one Bibliography based on multiple separate documents...

Comment: @ebo do you need bibliography and toc mid-production?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Fair question. I'd say yes, e.g. when I especially focus on updating the toc/bibliography style (that's why I'd like aux-files not to be overwritten). But you're right, this should not be a major issue mid-production.

Comment: ther was a long and somewhat fractious series of questions earlier in the year with someone asking questions while trying to implement a system like this, but all the questions were doomed to have unsatisfactory answers as the facility isn't really implementable. I'll see if I can find the link...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! "*there is no standard way to do this*" might indeed be the answer (for now)

Comment: see this and other questions from same user https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356074/problem-caching-files-aux-data-not-importing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just think that adding a page in a chapter changes all page numbers... adding a figure may change table of figures and extend it to a new page... a citation may change the order of all citations... So, you can not do what you ask for. LaTeX supposed to be clever typesetting system because it uses every letter to decide what to do with rhe whole document.

Comment: I am aware that not updating some chapters of my document would mean these chapter (namely page numbers, hyperlinks, toc, etc.) not *up-to-date* anymore. I also know that updating these information basically means recompiling those chapters (what I'd like to avoid). I'm thus rather focusing on including the *content* of these chapters in the produced document. That is, trading a large (and potentially frequent) compilation time against a bit of  not up-to-date minor information. (Note that each chapter starts on a new (right) page, what would things a bit easier.)

Comment: This is not completely true: `\include` can help. But when page numbers change, the document has to be fully typeset.

Comment: Yes... it starts in a new page... but it could need a new empy page before and different numbers for every page... LaTeX can not know that you don't care about the wrong numbers... the extra pages etc... It has to give an updated document using the changes it sees ... I can understand your point... but this is something that not needed to almost anybody (than you)... everybody can work with the only updated chapter or with the whole book... The functionality you ask for is too complicated for what offers... May be a script could do that... but not LaTeX... LaTeX has to be more "correct"

Comment: Just think that the numbers of the equations could be all defferent... etc... LaTeX has to do a serious job... and can not decide that you don't need serious job for the moment...

Comment: I thought that the answer "Your request can not be done" was an acceptable answer in this question... This is why I gave it as an answer... If someone ask "How can LaTeX ignore all my mistakes and typos and provide a perfect pdf?" an acceptable answer is "This can not be done!"... But I will avoid giving such answers in the future... Sorry

Comment: (Disclaimer: I [voted for](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/125357) this question not to be deleted.) @koleygr I'd say that the one who flagged your answer (I don't thinks it's Henri) might have thought your answer rather looks like a comment than an elaborated answer. You might want to highlight your point at the beginning of your answer. The automatic comment from review is a bit 'raw', and it might be difficult not to take it personally though - I totally understand.